# I am not getting google maps onTouchEvent events

Tags: android, google-maps, touch-event

I am trying to learn about Google maps API.  I have a project that shows the map, sets coordinates and does zoom in and out. I am trying to add an onTouch event.  I have:

```
class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {...}
```

and added

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)
```

All seems fine but the `onTouchEvent` is never called.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onTouchEvent Listener should be inside of MapOverlay class.